# What's the source of the covers of this edition of the Jerusalem Quartet (Sinai Tapestry, etc.)?

Tags: physical-books, edward-whittemore

Here are the covers for the four books of the Jerusalem Quartet by Edward Whittemore, in one of the first published editions:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

I'm looking for the source of the different images used on the covers. Books 1 and 3 images look like medieval engraving. Book 2 image is obviously a face from a standard deck of cards, but I'm interested in knowing the exact design used here. I'm not sure where book 4 image could come from.

Comment: Image 4 looks like it might have originally been an optical illusion — see the Wikipedia article on the [Rubin vase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubin_vase). But it seems there might be some details missing between the title words.